# Остановка VlcMediaPlayer занимает слишком много времени

Tags: vlc

Я написала простое WPF приложение. Приложение записывает поток RTSP в файл. Для этой цели используется библиотека Vlc.DotNet.

Я протестировала приложение на двух компьютерах и получила одинаковые результаты.

Код приложения предоставлен ниже.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private IPath _pathWrapper;
        private IDirectoryInfo _vlcLibDirectory;
        private VlcMediaPlayer _videoRecorder;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_videoRecorder != null && _videoRecorder.IsPlaying())
            {
                _videoRecorder.Stop();
                Button.Background = Brushes.Blue;
                _videoRecorder = null;
                return;
            }

            string currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            _pathWrapper = new PathWrap();
            _vlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfoWrap(_pathWrapper.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));
            var options = new string[]
            {
                "--file-logging",
                "--logfile=OnvifVideoRecording.log",
                "-vvv"
            };
            _videoRecorder = new VlcMediaPlayer(_vlcLibDirectory.DirectoryInfo, options);

            //string fileDestination = "\\\\\\BuildSrv\\Videos\\A, A, 1\\test.mp4";
            string fileDestination = @"D:\Media\Video\A, A, 1\test.mp4";

            if (File.Exists(fileDestination))
            {
                File.Delete(fileDestination);
            }

            string[] mediaOptions =
            {
                ":sout=#file{dst='" + fileDestination + "'}",
                ":sout-keep"
            };

            _videoRecorder.SetMedia("rtsp://192.168.1.110:5504/channel=0,stream=0", mediaOptions);
            _videoRecorder.Play();
            Button.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
```

В приложении имеется окно. В окне есть кнопка. Когда эта кнопка нажата в первый раз, начинается запись видео файла, и кнопка становится красной. Я обычно записываю видео файлы по 10 минут. Когда кнопка нажимается во второй раз, запись видео файла останавливается, и кнопка становится синей.

Если я записываю файл локально (на ту же машину, где выполняется программа, например, D:\Media\Video\A, A, 1\test.mp4), все отлично. Запись видео файла начинается и останавливается быстро, практически моментально.

Проблемы появляются, когда я записываю видео файл на другую машину (например, \BuildSrv\Videos\A, A, 1\test.mp4). Запись видео файла начинается сразу. Однако, выполнение _videoRecorder.Stop() занимает от 30 секунд до 1 минуты. Resource monitor оказывает очень высокое использоваие сети (90% в случае одного компьютера и 100% в случае другого) после того, как кнопка нажата во второй раз (запись видео остановлена). Чем больше записанный видео файл, тем больше времени занимает остановка VlcMediaPlayer.

Почему остановка VlcMediaPlayer занимает так много времени в случае записи потока RTSP на удаленный компьютер? Можно ли решить эту проблему?

Comment: Это точно rtsp? Не запись на сетевой диск?)

Comment: Не знаю, помогите разобратся. Насколько я понимаю, это запись RTSP потока в файл на сервер.